# Add product id to cart item class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get the `product_id` for an item in cart and then echo it to a class (custom `id`), so I can style items individually.

I have this:

```
<?php
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        break;
    }
    $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
?> 

<li id="mcitem-<?php echo esc_attr($cart_item_key); ?>" class="custom-<?php echo $product_id'; ?>">
```

This part was already in the mini-cart.php template, and so was the `li` but without the class attribute, which I added.

```
$product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

I tried to `echo $product_id` in different ways inside the class:

```
echo '$product_id';
echo esc_attr($product_id);
```

Tested both and didn't work. Then I found this snippet:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    break;
}
```

(also tested it without the break, so it has been tested inside and outside of loop)

Then I repeated the two echos, but still blank echo result (none).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you dump  WC()->cart->get_cart() and $cart_item['product_id'] (and if those seem fine, then also dump $product_id afer calling the apply_filters function

Comment: @flynorc - you are talking about var_dump() right? how would i do that? My php skills i very weak.

Comment: you would add var_dump( WC()->cart->get_cart()); before the foreach loop. and you would add var_dump($cart_item['product_id']); inside the foreach loop

Comment: @flynorc Which of the foreach loops? The one with the apply filter?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a class to the cart row, you can filter `woocommerce_cart_item_class`.

```
/**
 * Changes the tr class of cart items.
 *
 * @param  string  $class
 * @param  array   $values
 * @param  string  $values_key
 * @return string
 */
function so_42237701_cart_item_class( $class, $values, $values_key ) {

    if ( isset( $values[ 'product_id' ] ) ) {
        $class .= ' custom-' . $values[ 'product_id' ];
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'so_42237701_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
```

And for the mini cart:

```
/**
 * Changes the tr class of items in the mini-cart.
 *
 * @param  string  $class
 * @param  array   $values
 * @param  string  $values_key
 * @return string
 */
function so_42237701_mini_cart_item_class( $class, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item[ 'product_id' ] ) ) {
        $class .= ' custom-' . $cart_item[ 'product_id' ];
    }

    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'so_42237701_mini_cart_item_class', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: it's on the mini cart drop down, from menu, not the cart itself, but this is still useful as i might need it for cart later. Thanks. Do you know a fix for the mini cart?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It looks like the mini cart has a similar filter called [`woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b81e56b597b44b920af0e90095baea655dcd2394/templates/cart/mini-cart.php#L46). I'll edit, but it should be pretty much the same.

Comment: Not working it seems. Doesn't apply any class. Weird.

Comment: Looks like I had a couple of typos. I'm surprised you didn't get any errors. Tested and working now for me.

Comment: I fixed 1 typo, the apotstroph you also corrected. Did you find more?

Comment: Yes, previously I had `public function` since I had copied it out of a class. Since it's not in a class it doesn't need that and that should have caused an error.

Comment: Well - tried putting it in functions.php and mini-cart.php nothing works.

Comment: It belongs in `functions.php`. Can you make sure that you have [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) enabled. You may have an error somewhere that is preventing it from working, because it's functioning [here](https://wc26-helgatheviking.c9users.io/shop/page/4/).

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Check yourself on feropa.dk - the only thing it adds id the mcitem id, followed på the item cart key.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what `feropa.dk` is? If you are overriding the `cart.php` and/or `mini-cart.php` templates, please revert to the default WooCommerce templates (you can just temporarily rename them). If your templates don't have `woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class` or `woocommerce_cart_item_class` then my code won't do anything.

Comment: Feropa.dk is my site. Let me send you my mini-cart.php (gist link) in a second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135810/discussion-between-helgatheviking-and-magnus-pilegaard).